# jQuery Calculate height before class is applied

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to get jQuery to calculate the height of an element, and then add a class which I'll use to set the height of the element to 0px in CSS.

My problem is that jQuery is not making these calculations in the right order. This is what I would like to happen...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  elementHeight = $('div#test').outerHeight(true); // Calculate the height of the element before we do anything else
}, $('div#test').addClass('zeroheight')); // Once we've calculated add a CSS class
```

the CSS...

```
#test {
  height: 0;
}
```

Now, say the natural element height is 300px - the variable elementHeight should return 300px right, because I am only applying a class to change the height after the addClass has been performed?

But it's returning 0px instead.

Can someone give me a solution on how to get the 300px value as a calculation before I add a class to set the height to 0?

Many thanks

Comment: You have a syntax error in you javascript, not closing the docready properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var elementHeight = $('#test').height();
     $('#test').addClass('zeroheight');
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/AGfwJ/1/)

Comment: That worked, not sure why I didn't try that in the first place, but thanks!